# Trying to populate 16 random images using Math.random and a filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get 16 random images, but I am getting 1 of the same image. I know a change needs to be made to the `one => one.number` filter, but tries have failed.

```
import React from "react";
import { getCard } from "../redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import CardBoard from "./CardBoard";

class Board extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCard();
  }
  render() {
    let gameCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * (54 - 2) + 2);
    const game = () => {
      let cards = [];
      if (cards.length < 16) {
        cards.push(gameCard);
      }
      return cards;
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.cards
          .filter(one => one.number === gameCard)
          .map(card => (
            <CardBoard
              key={card._id}
              id={card._id}
              name={card.name}
              number={card.number}
              imgUrl={card.imgUrl}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => state,
  { getCard }
)(Board);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow B L! There is not quite enough information in your question for us to help you, sadly. Do you think you could include your entire component?

Comment: Thank you Tholle, I have updated to include the entire component

Comment: Great. You are using the `cards` from your `props`, but you are never using the `game` function you create in your `render` method. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes, the game should be in place of gameCard in the filter. I need to filter to get the 16 different game cards. Right now I am currently getting one card 16 times... I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I understand. And will there be more than 16 cards in `this.props.cards`, or do you want to tolerate duplicates in the result?

Comment: yes, there are a total of 54 cards and i do not want duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a function that randomly selects 16 cards from the cards given to your component and use those:

```
function getRandom(arr, n) {
  const arrLength = arr.length;
  const result = [];
  const taken = [];

  while (result.length !== n && result.length !== arrLength) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength);

    if (!taken.includes(random)) {
      result.push(arr[random]);
      taken.push(random);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCard();
  }

  render() {
    const cards = getRandom(this.props.cards, 16);

    return (
      <div>
        {cards.map(card => (
          <CardBoard
            key={card._id}
            id={card._id}
            name={card.name}
            number={card.number}
            imgUrl={card.imgUrl}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you always push just 1 item into your array. Here:

```
let cards = [];
if (cards.length < 16) {
  cards.push(gameCard);
}
```

Instead of this, try a do while statement:

```
do {
  cards.push(gameCard);
}
while (cards.length <= 16);
```